# Webpack 4 loader implement angular template cache so bundle can run be treat as complete library with view

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am using angular 1.x and creating library of which containing directive which have template URL. I am working with webpack. In development mode it is working fine but when i am trying to use it in other projects then it gives error template url not found.

Comment: replace `templateUrl: 'some/url/to/template.html'` with `template: require('some/url/to/template.html')`

Comment: @AdityaParab same issue using require, actually i need to add template caching for html template in build so it can easily accessed from other modules but i am not finding any standard html template loader for angular template cache. please if you have any idea about template caching loader ?

Comment: Okay. then Look up `copy-webpack-plugin` and add a plugin for prod mode to copy your html templates at the same relative path

Comment: @AdityaParab Thanks this is correct we can proceed with it but i am trying to look loader which is implement template cached with in bundle.js like
`$templateCache.put('templateId.html', '<span>lajsdhakjdh</span>');`

Comment: I guess you're misunderstanding the concept of bundles. If you use some sort of loader, anything you load with it will be added to the bundle. Therefore it will be shipped inside a bundle and you will no longer have dynamically loaded content. Since you will be loading entire bundle, that will also make question the need of some caching mechanism.

Comment: If you still want to utilize `$templateCache` for whatever reason, I'd recommend you do something along the lines of `var template1= require('template1.html); var template2 = require('template2.html'); $templateCache.put(template1, template2);`